# Vector image in a .pptx exported to PDF: how can I avoid quality loss?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf

I hope someone can help me fix this.

I created a round icon using Illustrator, saved it as a PNG and inserted it into a .pptx file. So far, so good.

Now when I save my .pptx document as a .pdf, the icon suffers a major quality loss. Even when I zoom in on the .pdf, the icon is not a perfect circle anymore and can become blurry, which just looks messy.

When creating the PNG from Illustrator, I've tried saving the icon in various sizes, to no avail. I've also tried tweaking the resolution using Photoshop (from 72 to 150 then 300 ppi), but still can't get to a satisfactory result.

Has any one of you ever encountered this issue and found a solution for it? Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: It ceased to be a vector image the moment you exported it as png. PNG is fine for screen, but not for pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Powerpoint support vector format and some of the EPS's can be imported directly into powerpoint as a vector format.

but to be in the safe side try to export your artwork from illustrator as 'EMF' this is a vector format developed my Microsoft and it could be imported into powerpoint without any problem and it remain vector even when exported to 'PDF'.

Comment: Except microsofts rendering  of vector data isnt really all that nice.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is not to "export" to a pdf format but to "print it" on a pdf file.

There are several virtual printers you can install for free, or use the adobe acrobat program. There are some online services that can convert your files too.